# Can I set a minimum number of required images for a channel images field?

Tags: channel-images, devdemon

I can set a *maximum* limit on the number of images a user can upload. Is there a way to set a *minimum*? I need to force users to upload 5 images, no more, no less.

Answer (score 4):

Currently Channel Images does not support this feature. You can request the feature for the future in our support portal. If you need it now, we are available for custom work as well. Feel free to contact us on the Support Portal.